# Why App Icon background looks different in iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have App icon with .png format with white background with propers sizes as per apple.
But it looks proper with white background on iPhone but on iPad its background looks black.

But ideally it should look like same on both, with white background on iPad.

Is there any specific reason or solution for this?

Comment: are you sure that app icon same for iPhone and iPad. can you tel me in brif how do you set icon for iPhone and iPad. can you show me screenshot of xcode that you setting icon for app

Comment: Same problem with me

Comment: Yes I have same for both, both are .png file ad drag drop to Appiconset, with to warnings for sizes